# Do the representatives from some conjugacy classes generate a normal subgroup?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof of Lemma 3 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.07036), which states:

**Lemma 3**. Consider a group $G$ and a set $S \subset \mathrm{Conj}(G)$ of conjugacy classes of $G$, with the property that $\chi_\rho([g]) = \chi_ρ(1)$ for all $[g] \in S$ only if $\rho$ is the trivial representation of $G$. Then the representatives of the conjugacy classes in $S$ generate the entire group $G$.

The proof they give makes sense to me, except for the initial statement which is crucial. They say that

> The representatives of the conjugacy classes in $S$ generate a subgroup $H$ of $G$. Because it is constructed from conjugacy classes, this subgroup is normal: $H \leq G$.

My question is: **why is the subgroup $H$ normal?**

I'm aware that, for example, if we pick a representative from each conjugacy class, these generate the group. I'm also aware that a subgroup generated by conjugacy classes is normal. But why should representatives from *some* conjugacy classes generate a normal subgroup? This statement seems strange: suppose that I pick a representative of *one* conjugacy class. This will generate a cyclic subgroup, and in fact any cyclic subgroup can be generated this way. Then their statement would imply that every cyclic subgroup is normal, which is clearly false. What am I missing?

Comment: The point is that they do not pick a representative from each conjugacy class, they take *all* representatives, i.e. all elements, of all the classes in $S$.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim Hi, thanks for your comment. That would make the statement true, but this is not the standard usage of the term "representative". I'm confused, because if they really meant that they take all elements, the statement could have been written much more clearly.

Comment: I agree that it could have been said much more clearly. Still, I believe that is what they meant. The group generated by all elements of the conjugacy classes is indeed the "conjugacy closure" of the set you are describing, i.e. the smallest normal subgroup containing a set of representatives. 

Even if that was not what they meant, and they were confused, I believe this fixes the proof for them.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim Thank you for your comment. If this indeed what they meant, I agree it fixes the proof. However, I would like to see if anybody else has a different take on this

Comment: The result I think is not true if we just take one element from each of the conjugacy classes in $S$ and generate a subgroup. Take the semidirect product of $C_3$ and $C_7$. Now the conjugacy classes are the identity, two size 3 conjugacy class of elements of order 7 and seven conjugacy classes of elements of order 3. Let $S$ be the set containing two conjugacy classes of elements of order $3$. Pick one element each from the conjugacy classes so that you generated a cyclic group of order $3$.

Comment: But it can be shown that are characters $\chi$ where $\chi(g)\neq \chi(1)$ where $\chi(g)$ is the element of order 3 you picked. In other words, I agree with SomeCallMeTim.

Comment: @daruma Thank you for taking the time to work out a counterexample. If you write that up as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1):

It seems that theorem as stated is incorrect. Instead, one can prove the following cleaned-up version:

**Lemma 3**. Consider a group $G$ and a subset $S \subset G$, which is a union of  of conjugacy classes of $G$. Suppose that there are no non-trivial irreducible characters of $G$ such that $\chi(g)=\chi(1)$ for all $g \in S$. Then $S$ generates $G$.

The proof is the same as that given in the linked paper.